# TensorFlow: How to concatenate tensors by duplicating one of the tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to concatenate two tensors by duplicating one of the tensor. For example, I have two tensors of shape [2, 2, 3] and [2, 3]. The result should be in the shape of [2, 2, 6].

```
t1 = [[[ 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]],
      [[ 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]]
t2 = [[ 5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6]]
"""
t3 = # some tf ops
t3 should be
t3 = [[[ 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5], [2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]],
      [[ 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6], [4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6]]]
"""
```

So If the two tensors are of shape [10, 5, 8] and [10, 3], the result should be of shape [10, 5, 11].

**UPDATED**

Another example:

```
t1 = np.reshape(np.arange(3*4*5), [3,4,5])
t2 = np.reshape(np.arange(3*1*2), [3,2])
""""
t3 should be
  [[[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   0.,   1.],
    [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,   0.,   1.],
    [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,   0.,   1.],
    [ 15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,   0.,   1.]],

   [[ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.,   2.,   3.],
    [ 25.,  26.,  27.,  28.,  29.,   2.,   3.],
    [ 30.,  31.,  32.,  33.,  34.,   2.,   3.],
    [ 35.,  36.,  37.,  38.,  39.,   2.,   3.]],

   [[ 40.,  41.,  42.,  43.,  44.,   4.,   5.],
    [ 45.,  46.,  47.,  48.,  49.,   4.,   5.],
    [ 50.,  51.,  52.,  53.,  54.,   4.,   5.],
    [ 55.,  56.,  57.,  58.,  59.,   4.,   5.]]]
"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `tf.tile` can help you make it. Click [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile) to get detail of the function.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

t1 = np.reshape(np.arange(3*4*5), [3,4,5])
t2 = np.reshape(np.arange(3*1*2), [3,2])

# Keep t1 stay
t1_p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3,4,5])

# Change t2 from shape(3,2) to shape(3,4,2) followed below two steps:
#    1. copy element of 2rd dimension of t2 as many times as you hope, as the updated example, it is 4
#    2. reshape the tiled tensor to compatible shape
t2_p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3,2])
# copy the element of 2rd dimention of t2 by 4 times
t2_p_tiled = tf.tile(t2_p, [1, 4])
# reshape tiled t2 with shape(3,8) to the compatible shape(3,4,2)
t2_p_reshaped = tf.reshape(t2_p_tiled, [3,4,2])

# Concat t1 and changed t2, then you will get t3 you want
t3_p = tf.concat([t1_p, t2_p_reshaped], 2)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
t3 = sess.run(t3_p, {t1_p:t1, t2_p:t2})

print '*' * 20
print t1
print '*' * 20
print t2
print '*' * 20
print t3

# if you confused what the tf.tile did, you can print t2_p_tiled to see what happend
t2_tile = sess.run(t2_p_tiled, {t2_p:t2})
print '*' * 20
print t2_tile
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the function pack https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#pack

The code should be something similar to this:

```
t2 = tf.transpose(t2)
tf.pack([t1, tf.pack(t2,t2, axis=1)], axis=2)
```

**UPDATE**

> So If the two tensors are of shape [10, 5, 8] and [10, 3], the result
>   should be of shape [10, 5, 11].

I am not sure this is possible. Can you write down how are this tensors and how the result tensor should be? The second dimension of the first and result tensors it is not something you can create from scratch for the second tensor.

Comment: If this works, it only works when the first dimension is 2, right?

Comment: I don't understand you well. One tensor has 2 dimensions and the other has 3. That is the reason of the pack of t2 with t2. So t2 has 3 dimensions and can be packed with t1. Axis is the dimension you want to do the pack. Something like this will work for your example but for different shapes you will probably need to change